# stripe.redirectToCheckout: You must provide one of lineItems, items, or sessionId

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments

I've been integrating Stripe checout into my website for some weeks now. The content will be dynamic with the name/description & price set during the checkout process.

I am currently running the following:

Create-checkout-session.php

```
<?php
require('../config.php');
require_once('../includes/stripe-php/init.php');

// Set your secret key. Remember to switch to your live secret key in production!
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
 \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_lF...');

 $checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
 'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
 'line_items' => [[
'name' => 'T-shirt',
'description' => 'Description of item',
'images' => ['https://example.com/t-shirt.png'],
'amount' => 500,
'currency' => 'gbp',
'quantity' => 1,
]],
'success_url' => 'https://example.com/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
'cancel_url' => 'https://example.com/cancel',
]);


?>
```

The checkout session ID can be echo'd onto the main page using

```
    <?php echo json_encode($checkout_session['id']) ?>
```

Within the script I have buyingPhoto button that triggers this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#buyingPhoto').on('click', function() {

    var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_CX...');
         console.log("Can a button be depressed?")
            stripe.redirectToCheckout({
                // Make the id field from the Checkout Session creation API response
                // available to this file, so you can provide it as parameter here
                // instead of the {{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}} placeholder.
                sessionId: document.$checkout_session
            }).then(function (result) {
                // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
                // error, display the localized error message to your customer
                // using `result.error.message`.
            });
});
});
```

However I get the reference error. Except for changing the domain for success/cancel what am I missing please?

Comment: can you show where you're setting document.$checkout_session? Is that the string ID of the Checkout Session on the client?

Comment: This variable is created in create-checkout-session.php
        $checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([

And returns the checkout session ID (as checked on stripe dashboard)

Comment: okay but it doesn't look like that's accessible on the client inside of your buyingPhoto click handler. I think you may want to replace `document.$checkout_session` with `<?php echo $checkout_session->id ?>` so that the ID of the session is rendered directly into that sessionId field.

        var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_CX...');
         console.log("Session ID", '<? php echo $checkout_session->id ?>')
            stripe.redirectToCheckout({
                sessionId: '<?php echo $checkout_session->id ?>',
            }).then(function (result) {
            });

Answer (score 1):

For your code to work client-side, you need to pass the Checkout `Session` id `cs_test_123456` client-side in the `sessionId` parameter.

At the moment, your code is passing `sessionId: document.$checkout_session` where this variable is likely not initialized. My guess is that you are trying to access the PHP variable in Javascript which doesn't work that way as they are separate environments. Instead, you need to fix your JS code to properly get the value in the PHP variable.

If you are mixing JS and PHP in one file the easiest would be to do this:

```
sessionId: '<?php echo $checkout_session->id; >?',
```

If you are not and have separated PHP and JS, then you need to find a way to load the value from the PHP variable, the same way you would load other information from your server.

Comment: That code snippet doesn't work as the code base is seperate (JS & PHP) so i'm now looking for a way to pass a variable between the scripts.

Comment: @Brad Unfortunately the way to pass data between PHP and JS really depends on how your application is set up, what framework you use, etc. But if your client makes a request to your server, for example via Ajax, you would need to return the checkout session id in the JSON response and then access it in Javascript. This should work the same way anything is sent from your PHP code to your client.

Comment: Thank you Koopa. 
I'm extremely rusty with Ajax but i'm going to refresh this or I've seen an example where the checkout_session is generated same JS function

Answer (score 0):

it is because you should only fire this code when you create the session with the php code. So if you move your code to the page where/when you make a session then you won't get the error!!